# Twitter Bootstrap menu acting differently depending on order of scripts

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am attempting to use twitter boot strap with asp.net webforms to create responsive menu's.

```
    <link href="includes/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="includes/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="includes/sitestyles.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>


    <script type="text/javascript">

           $(function () {
               //to fix collapse mode width issue
               $(".nav li,.nav li a,.nav li ul").removeAttr('style');

               //for dropdown menu
              $(".dropdown-menu").parent().removeClass().addClass('dropdown');
              $(".dropdown>a").removeClass().addClass('dropdown-toggle').append('<b class="caret"></b>').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');

               //remove default click redirect effect           
              $('.dropdown-toggle').attr('onclick', '').off('click');

           });
   </script>
   <script src="includes/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am running into an issue where if I include the `bootstrap.min.js` after my inline jquery the menu will cut of drowdown items and the jquery seems to have no effect
[image]

but if I include the `bootstrap.min.js` before my inline jquery. The toggle menu button will not display any menu items. Below is my full code for the menu portion of the page.

```
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
             <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
        <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal"
                    CssClass="navbar navbar-fixed-top"
                    StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav"
                    StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="active"
                    DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown-menu">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" ToolTip="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Music" ToolTip="Music">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Classical" ToolTip="Classical" />
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Rock" ToolTip="Rock" />
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Jazz" ToolTip="Jazz" />
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Movies" ToolTip="Movies">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Action" ToolTip="Action" />
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Drama" ToolTip="Drama" />
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Musical" ToolTip="Musical" />
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I was trying to reproduce the content from the example  [Responsive ASP.NET Menu Control With Twitter Bootstrap](http://techbrij.com/responsive-menu-twitter-bootstrap-asp-net).

Can someone tell me what order I should be including my scripts and why neither of the ways seems to work? I am leaning towards the  inline jquery coming last being the right order but cant figure out why the toggle menu button doesn't work.

**EDIT**

I have noticed that if I perform my in file javascript then include the bootstrap.min.js file followed again by my in file java script things work.

Comment: From your previously posted question, I created my own test using your code and it work correctly for me first try. Have you checked that your custom CSS is not messing it up? Try removing your custom CSS file.

Comment: @Schmalzy Removing my custom css did not change anything. Although I have noticed that if I perform my in file javascript then include the bootstrap.min.js file followed again by my in file java script things work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is your jQuery `<script>` tag. You cannot self-close script tags `<script />` you have to have an open and close tag `<script></script>`

Which would explain why the following script is not working correctly, and why it did work correctly when you added the custom script twice.

Comment: Thats what it was. Added the closing script tag to the jquery include and  it works. Man do I fell like an idiot Thanks for the help